# Can Anyone spot the error here

Tags: c

Here is a code I m currently working upon. It is related to array of structures. This     program is currently working fine. But If I replace the data type of salary variable in  the structure employee to float, a logical error arises. I cannot enter the salary value while scanf.Even if I change the format specifier, the problem persists.

Can anybody locate the error and how would it be resolved?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct employee
{
int emp_no;
char emp_name[25];
int salary;
};

void main()
{
   struct employee emp[2];
   int i;
   clrscr();
   for(i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
       printf("enter details for employee #%d:\n",(i+1));
       printf("code:");
       scanf("%d",&emp[i].emp_no);
       printf("name:");
       scanf("%s",emp[i].emp_name);
       printf("salary:");
       scanf("%d",&emp[i].salary);
   }
   printf("\n");
   for(i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
       printf("details of employee #%d are:\n", (i+1));
       printf("code: %d\n", emp[i].emp_no);
       printf("name: %s\n", emp[i].emp_name);
       printf("salary: %d\n", emp[i].salary);
   }
   getch();
}
```

Comment: When you changed `salary` to float, have you changed the format in your `scanf` and `printf` calls to `%f` (instead of `%d`) ?

Comment: What's the error? The number you enter is not recognised? The program crashes?

Comment: "I cannot enter the salary value while scanf." - what exactly happens when you attempt to enter it? "Even if I change the format specifier, the problem persists." - what do you change the format specifier to? Do you change it in both the corresponding `scanf` and `printf` calls?

Comment: Please post the code that **doesn't** work.

Comment: After this change the program exits out when i try to enter the salary

Comment: Then, when viewed the output with Alt + F5. It says the floating point formats not linked. Abnormal program termination

Comment: You should edit your question to include this detail (fp format not linked), because it changes everything.

Answer (score 2):

http://c-faq.com/fp/fpnotlinked.html

Your compiler is optimizing the output binary size and is not linking with floating point formatting. Check your compiler/linker settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just include this function after your main function:

`static void force_fpf(){`

float x,*y;

y=&x;

x=*y;

}

This will run your program successfully

Comment: Allllll right: this forces the compiler to link with the floating point library instead of the one without, thus enabling all the floating points operations. See [Leeor Aharon's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744238/can-anyone-spot-the-error-here/6745233#6745233) answer for an explanation.

Comment: Some compilers for small machines, including Turbo C , leave out floating point support if it looks like it will not be needed. In particular, the non-floating-point versions of printf and scanf save space by not including code to handle %e, %f, and %g. It happens that Turbo C's heuristics for determining whether the program uses floating point are insufficient, and the programmer must sometimes insert an extra, explicit call to a floating-point library routine to force loading of floating-point support. So the above function i used forces the compiler. Gui13 you are correct